# Websocket dont recieve messages with Python

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I'm trying to connect to the binance futures websocket, but I can't get it to work. Here its the link to the api:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#continuous-contract-kline-candlestick-streams

my code:

```
SOCKET = 'wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/trxusdt_PERPETUAL@continuousKline_1m'
def on_message(ws,msg):
    print(msg)
def on_open(ws):
    print('connect')
def start():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_message=on_message, on_open=on_open)
    ws.run_forever()

start()
```

Can someone help me how to do it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
Ok, the problem is that it capitalizes perpetual. The solution was to put everything in lowercase, in this case "trxusdt_perpetual"